# My simple html php form not inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For some reason, this form doesn't insert into my database.

**Html**

```
<form action="../php/register.php" method="post">
    <div id ="personal-form">
        <h4><b>Personal Details:</b></h4>
        <hr>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="first-name">First name</label>
            First Name

            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="" 
                   class="form-control" id="firstname">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-next" id="submit">
                Submit
            </button>
        </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**php/register.php**

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO storeowners (firstname) VALUES 
(:firstname)");

        $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
        $stmt->execute();

        header("location: next.php");
    }
?>
```

This is **connect.php**

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=blaza", $username, 
$password);
        //set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "success";
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

When I click on submit button, it shows the **php/register.php** page with the message **success** which is thesame message in the **connect.php** code if db connection was successful.
I dont know where the problem is cause it doesnt store the firstname to the database and no error was given.

Comment: `for="first-name"` & `id="firstname"` do not match.

Comment: you have a closing `</center>` tag with no opening one (not a php issue but an issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `name="submit"` to your button.

```
<form action="../php/register.php" method="post">
      <div id ="personal-form">
        <h4><b>Personal Details:</b></h4>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="sr-only" for="first-name">First name</label>
              First Name
           <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="" class="form-control" id="firstname">
           <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-next" id="submit">Submit</button></center>
       </div>
     </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
> ```

You have no form controls with `name=submit` so this condition will never be true.

You connect to the database unconditionally, but you never use the connection to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $_POST["submit"] add this

```
if(isset($_POST["firstname"]))
```